# How to pass PyHANDLE object to CP2108 dll functions (CP210xRuntime.dll) in Python?

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I need to control CP2108 chips Latch using Python. 
C# example code (from manufacturers example source):

```
comString.Format(_T("\\\\.\\COM%d"), m_COMPort.GetCurSel() + 1);
//Open a handle the the device specified
HANDLE hDevice = CreateFile(comString,
                            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                            0,
                            0,
                            OPEN_EXISTING,
                            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                            0);

//If the handle is valid, then it opened
if (hDevice != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    WORD latch = 0;
    //Read the latch
    if (CP210xRT_ReadLatch(hDevice, &latch) != CP210x_SUCCESS)
    {.....}
 }
```

Mine Python code:

```
import win32file
import win32con
import ctypes

cp201x_dll = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary('CP210xRuntime.dll')

lp_latch = ctypes.c_int(0)

h_device = win32file.CreateFile(r'\\.\\COM37',
                               win32con.GENERIC_READ|win32con.GENERIC_WRITE,
                               0,
                               None,
                               win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
                               win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL|win32con.FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                               None)



cp201x_dll.CP210xRT_ReadLatch(h_device, ctypes.byref(lp_latch))

print 'VALUE: {}'.format(lp_latch)
```

But I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Dropbox/ElgsisTests/src/lib/cp210x/practise.py", line 27, in <module>
    cp201x_dll.CP210xRT_ReadLatch(h_device, ctypes.byref(lp_latch))
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 1
```

I tried to pass ctypes integer, but i got Latch value of zero. I think it's because this CP210xRuntime.dll need an information about COM port.

From API manual:

```
 3.1. CP210xRT_ReadLatch
    Description:

 Gets the current port latch value from the device.

    Supported Devices: CP2103, CP2104, CP2105, CP2108
    Location: CP210x Runtime DLL
    Prototype: CP210x_STATUS CP210xRT_ReadLatch(HANDLE Handle, LPWORD Latch)
    Parameters: 1. Handle—Handle to the Com port returned by CreateFile().
    2. Latch—Pointer for 4-byte return GPIO latch value [Logic High = 1, Logic Low = 0].
    Return Value: CP210x_STATUS = CP210x_SUCCESS,
    CP210x_INVALID_HANDLE,
    CP210x_DEVICE_IO_FAILED
    CP210x_FUNCTION_NOT_SUPPORTED
```

So maybe someone knows how to pass it correctly?

Comment: Let's see...  `>>> dir(h_device)` .... Oh, it has a `handle` attribute and implements `__int__`, so use either `h_device.handle` or `int(h_device)`, preferably the latter [per the docs](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/PyHANDLE.html).

Comment: yes. I did find that it's an int... and right now CP210xRT_ReadLatch returns error code 0xFF and its not the list of return values...

Comment: and now its working:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

updated Python code with:

```
handle = ctypes.c_long(int(h_device))
status = cp201x_dll.CP210xRT_ReadLatch(handle, ctypes.byref(lp_latch))
print 'STATUS: {}'.format(status)
print 'VALUE: {}'.format(lp_latch)
```

And did received correct values

Comment: You don't need to wrap a file handle in `c_long`. kernel object handles always fit in the default `c_int` type, which on Windows is always the same size as a `c_long` anyway. Plus if you want to be technically correct, a Windows `HANDLE` is a typedef for `void *`, so you would use `c_void_p`. That's because a lot of handle types in Windows, e.g. `HMODULE`, are actually pointers -- just not file handles!